# My background image isn't fading in (but the nav bar is)

Tags: html, css

My background image is not fading in but my navbar is. (I want my background image to fade in and the navbar to not)

Here is the HTML

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #272727;
}

body.home {
  background-image: URL("Homebc.png");
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<body class="home">
  <div>
    <header="navbar">
      <div>
        <a class="logo" href="Index.html">
          <img src="brandlogoNAV.png" height="57.6px" width="190px">
        </a>
          <ul>
          <li><a class="active" href="Index.html">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT</a></li>
          <li><a href="Approach.html">OUR APPROACH</a></li>
          <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Everything will be fading in so long as you are declaring your key-frame animation on the `body` tag - the containing parent tag of all other tags. Also, I'm not sure you can apply this sort of animation to a background image, since it has to be requested and loaded from the server first - once it has been loaded you could probably apply animation or transition effects - but not during. You might be able to achieve something similar with javascript but I think that will exceed the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can not animate body background and your code has some issue too. Try below code-

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #272727;
}

.home {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/04/06/11/50/image-editing-101040_960_720.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vh;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="home">
      <header class="navbar">
          <div>
              <a class="logo" href="Index.html">
                  <img src="brandlogoNAV.png" height="57.6px" width="190px">
              </a>
              <ul>
                  <li><a class="active" href="Index.html">HOME</a></li>
                  <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Approach.html">OUR APPROACH</a></li>
                  <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You should replace the line:

```
<header="navbar">
```

With

```
<header class="navbar">
```

Then, the body selector on your CSS file don't have a corresponding end `}`.

Besides that, body background cannot be animated.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #272727;
}
body.home {
  background-image: url("http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  from { opacity: 0; }
  to   { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<body class="home">
  <div>
    <header class="navbar">
          <div>
              <a class="logo" href="Index.html">
                <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" height="57.6px" width="190px">
              </a>
              <ul>
                <li><a class="active" href="Index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="Approach.html">OUR APPROACH</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </header>
  </div>
</body>
```